# Interpretation of the Weibull survival analysis output, converting SE of the log hazard ratio estimate to natural scale

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

I am working on a survival analysis, which will provide an input for the decision analytic model (discrete event simulation that samples time to event from a survival curve). For that, I need shape and scale parameters and corresponding standard errors for three different competing events that can happen to people. The competing events are captured by the factor variable  `trans` .

I understand correctly that the shape and scale parameter for the reference category (i.e. occurance of event 1) are the estimates in the second column (1.4185, 25.8537). The estimates for both shape and scale of trans2 and trans3 are, however, a log hazard ratio and I need to calculate the exp(est)*est for reference category to get the shape/scale estimate on the natural scale (is natural scale an accurate terminology?). For instance, the shape for trans2 would be 0.9693*1.4185 =  1.374952. To test this, I rearranged my analysis so trans2 became a reference category and I received this as a shape estimate for the reference category.

What I still do not understand is how the standard errors for shape and scale of the trans2/trans3 can be calculated converting the SE of their log hazard ratio. For instance, the output below gives me SE for shape(trans2) = 0.0535. In the rearranged my analysis, SE for the referrence category is 0.0646. I do not see how to get the SE 0.0646 using the original output. I found something about a delta method, that effectivelly multiply the estimate on a natural scale with the standard error of an estimate on the log scale. In the provided example, it would be 1.374952*0.0535, which does not give the SE of 0.0646.

Last, this is an unadjusted analysis. I am wondering, how the shape and scale parameters for the weibull survival curves would be calculated in case more variables were added such as sex. To illustrate, I would be interested to extract a shape and scale for a survival curve for event2 (trans2) for women.

Output 1

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trans + shape(trans), 
    data = long.mild, subset = (long.mild$condition == 0), dist = "weibull")

Estimates: 
               data mean  est      L95%     U95%     se       exp(est)  L95%     U95%   
shape               NA     1.4185   1.3490   1.4917   0.0364       NA        NA       NA
scale               NA    25.8537  24.6060  27.1647   0.6525       NA        NA       NA
trans2          0.3333     0.8661   0.7277   1.0046   0.0707   2.3777    2.0702   2.7308
trans3          0.3333     1.0358   0.8741   1.1974   0.0825   2.8173    2.3968   3.3116
shape(trans2)   0.3333    -0.0312  -0.1360   0.0737   0.0535   0.9693    0.8728   1.0765
shape(trans3)   0.3333     0.1435   0.0206   0.2665   0.0627   1.1543    1.0208   1.3053
```

Output2 (rearranged analysis with where original trans2 is a refrence value)

```
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trans + shape(trans), 
    data = long.mild, subset = (long.mild$condition == 0), dist = "weibull")

Estimates: 
               data mean  est      L95%     U95%     se       exp(est)  L95%     U95%   
shape               NA     1.3750   1.2541   1.5076   0.0646       NA        NA       NA
scale               NA    61.4722  54.0142  69.9599   4.0565       NA        NA       NA
trans2          0.3333    -0.8661  -1.0046  -0.7277   0.0707   0.4206    0.3662   0.4830
trans3          0.3333     0.1696  -0.0314   0.3706   0.1026   1.1848    0.9691   1.4486
shape(trans2)   0.3333     0.0312  -0.0737   0.1360   0.0535   1.0316    0.9289   1.1457
shape(trans3)   0.3333     0.1747   0.0296   0.3198   0.0740   1.1909    1.0301   1.3769

N = 4434,  Events: 1173,  Censored: 3261
Total time at risk: 66624
Log-likelihood = -5494.606, df = 6
AIC = 11001.21
```

Comment: If this is the same type of data as in [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/550233/28500), then these don't seem to be "competing risks" but rather a set of transitions to progressively higher states. Please edit the question to say more about the underlying data and your hypothesis, as I don't think anyone will want to give you advice about how to proceed with a model that might not be appropriate for your study.